# Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus Displays wrong status (Microsoft Exchange)

Tags: powershell, exchange

When I execute the Exchange command in powershell, and below command is executed before executing Exchange command.

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010
The "Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus" command can display the correct status if I execute it with a user in Exchange "Organization Management" Group.

```
Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus | FL name,status
Name   : DB01\SERVER0246
Status : Mounted
```

But when I use a user in a group which has same roles as "Organization Management" Group.The result will look like below:

```
Name   : DB01\SERVER0246
Status : ServiceDown
```

I have searched for a long time on Internet, but I cannot find any explanation. Is there a way that I can get the right result for "Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus" command without adding the user in "Organization Management" Group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm here to narrow down the status issue:

- How did you execute the above command? Run it in the powershell with
  another user's credential, or switch to another user which is in a
  group that has same roles?
- Does the group which the second user locates in have the **Databases** and **Database Copies** role?

To find why the database status displayed "**ServiceDown**", you could add the **ErrorMessage** parameter in the above command(**Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus | fl Name, Status, ErrorMessage**):
[image]

Comment: 1. I execute the above command with another user which is in a group that has same roles.  2. The group whihc the second user locates have the Databases and Database Copies role.   3. I add the ErrorMessage, and when I run the command (Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus | fl Name, Status, ErrorMessage), the error message is: ErrorMessage : A server-side administrative operation has failed. Operation failed with message: Error 0x5 (Access is
               denied) from RpccGetCopyStatusEx4

Comment: Hi lvan, I found that even when I add the user in "Organization Management" group, it still cannot get teh right status. So I assume it may be not caused by the lack of this group,

Comment: Could you get the correct status via an admin account? According to your ErrorMessage,  it seems that the permission is the reason to cause this status issue, if admin account could get the correct status, maybe the granting the permission wasn't completed, try to reboot your server and grant the permission again or restart Replication service during non-working hours.

Comment: Hi lvan, thank you for your answer. Finally I found that the status can be got if I writes a service with the account who isn't in "Organization Management" group. The issue was resolved.

Comment: Hi, i'm glad that you have fixed the status issue, at the same time, you could mark the best answer to help people who have the same problem. Have a good day:)